# Buying used tower

Tags: tower

I'm thinking about buying a 70' self supporting tower that I can see had a little rust here and there.  Besides minor rust is there anything I should ask the seller before I buy?

Comment: What is the make and model number?

Comment: All I know is it is a Titan 72'

Comment: [This appears to be their website](http://trylon.com/products/stocked_towers.aspx).

Comment: I've never done something like that, but seeing that it is basically a building, and there's engineers that appraise/assess the state of buildings for selling/compensation reasons, I'd ask one to write an expert report. Asking might mean paying him money.

Answer (score 3):

You should first ask *the manufacturer*. They should be able to provide the all-important safety, erection, and guying information.

Study the manual and relevant info first, which probably is available on the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to ask a local (metal) engineering workshop. I have one near me (Surrey UK) that do a large amount of work for a nearby amusement park. They would be well used to assessing the state of the steel-work underneath the galvanising (I guess it is galvanised). If you pay for their advise you should then have some come-back if things go wrong. 
I would also take into account where I was going to site it, in particular where and on what it would fall should the worst happen.
Also - it is described as self-supporting - does this classification apply to all geographical areas? I am thinking here of wind-loading?
A point relevenat for when you put aerials up there.
Oh, and don't forget the base/foundation; the size of which is dependent on the last factor together with the type of soil in your area.